# An alternative: cut -d <string>?

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, text, cut

When I type `ls` I get:

```
aedes_aegypti_upstream_dremeready_all_simpleMasked_random.fasta
anopheles_albimanus_upstream_dremeready_all_simpleMasked_random.fasta
anopheles_arabiensis_upstream_dremeready_all_simpleMasked_random.fasta
anopheles_stephensi_upstream_dremeready_all_simpleMasked_random.fasta
culex_quinquefasciatus_upstream_dremeready_all_simpleMasked_random.fasta
```

I want to pipe this into cut (or via some alternative way) so that I only get:

```
aedes_aegypti
anopheles_albimanus
anopheles_arabiensis
anopheles_stephensi
culex_quinquefasciatus
```

If cut would accept a string (multiple characters) as it's delimiter then I could use:

```
cut -d "_upstream_" -f1
```

But that is not permitted as cut only takes single characters as delimiters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`awk` does allow a string as delimiter:

```
$ awk -F"_upstream_" '{print $1}' file
aedes_aegypti
anopheles_albimanus
anopheles_arabiensis
anopheles_stephensi
culex_quinquefasciatus
drosophila_melanogaster
```

Note for the given input you can also use `cut` with `_` as delimiter and print first two records:

```
$ cut -d'_' -f-2 file
aedes_aegypti
anopheles_albimanus
anopheles_arabiensis
anopheles_stephensi
culex_quinquefasciatus
drosophila_melanogaster
```

`sed` and `grep` can also make it. For example, this `grep` uses a look-ahead to print everything from the beginning of the line until you find `_upstream`:

```
$ grep -Po '^\w*(?=_upstream)' file
aedes_aegypti
anopheles_albimanus
anopheles_arabiensis
anopheles_stephensi
culex_quinquefasciatus
drosophila_melanogaster
```

Comment: Perfect answer!

Answer (score 4):

If you only want the first field, you could do this in pure bash:

```
ls | while read line; do echo "${line%%_upstream_*}"; done
```

Comment: so many alternative ways, I've learnt a little from each thank you!

Comment: @hello_there_andy no problem, that's what it's all about

Answer (score 4):

You could also use sed:

```
sed -i.bak 's/_upstream.*//' file
```

Result:

```
aedes_aegypti
anopheles_albimanus
anopheles_arabiensis
anopheles_stephensi
culex_quinquefasciatus
drosophila_melanogaster
```

Note: This will also create a backup of the original file as file.bak.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @Tom Fenech - using [bash parameter expansion/substring removal](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal) - but using a `for` loop:

```
$ ls
aedes_aegypti_upstream_dremeready_all_simpleMasked_random.fasta
anopheles_albimanus_upstream_dremeready_all_simpleMasked_random.fasta
anopheles_arabiensis_upstream_dremeready_all_simpleMasked_random.fasta
anopheles_stephensi_upstream_dremeready_all_simpleMasked_random.fasta
culex_quinquefasciatus_upstream_dremeready_all_simpleMasked_random.fasta
drosophila_melanogaster_upstream_dremeready_all_simpleMasked_random.fasta

$ for file in *; do
> echo "${file%%_upstream_*}"
> done
aedes_aegypti
anopheles_albimanus
anopheles_arabiensis
anopheles_stephensi
culex_quinquefasciatus
drosophila_melanogaster
```